# Одинаковый код и «exit»

Tags: delphi

Есть процедура, а в ней три строки повторяются несколько с процедурой "exit" раз.

```
procedure TForm1.rrr;
begin
  ...
  if … then
  begin
    PrErrorExistMeans := 0;
    mLog.Lines.Add(Title_File(C_Error_Means));
    Exit;
  end;
  ...
  if … then
  begin
    PrErrorExistMeans := 0;
    mLog.Lines.Add(Title_File(C_Error_Means));
    Exit;
  end;
  ...
  if … then
  begin
    PrErrorExistMeans := 0;
    mLog.Lines.Add(Title_File(C_Error_Means));
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Условия конечно разные, а так как мне нравится одинаковый код переносить в отдельные процедуры. – строки «`begin … end`», то я и тут перенес.

Только проблема с использованием «`Exit`», я хочу ее вынести тоже в отдельную процедуру/функцию (она выходит только со своей процедуры, а основная процедура продолжается). Программа не работает как нужно, а «`Abort`» вообще выкидывает «Access violation».

Что можно тут сделать?

Comment: Как вариант, если позволяют условия, можно переписать на `case of`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Procedure TForm1.rrr;
Begin
  ...
  try
    If … then
    Begin
      ...
      exit;
    End;

    If … then
    Begin
      ...
      exit;
    End;

  finally
    PrErrorExistMeans := 0;
    mLog.Lines.Add(Title_File(C_Error_Means));
  end;
End;
```

Comment: Скажите, а никак нельзя в отдельную процедуру выделиить?

Comment: @Konstantin78 Ключевое слово `exit` имеет смысл в контексте выполняемой процедуры (как `return` в С-языках).

Comment: Да, конечно. 
  Спасибо

Comment: Ну тогда просто: If ... then exit (без begin и end, потому что только эти строки там участвуют)

Comment: или просто тогда, сделать отдельную процедуру и перенести только две (в конкретном примере) строки кода: *PrErrorExistMeans := 0;
    mLog.Lines.Add(Title_File(C_Error_Means));* без *exit*

Comment: главное чтобы между ифами другого кода не было, а то тоже в finally попадет.

Answer (score 0):

Вынести `Exit` во внешний (или вложенный) метод не получится, но можно использовать механизм исключений, тогда вместо `Exit` нужно использовать наследника от `Exception`:

```pascal
type
  EExitException = class(Exception);

procedure MyCommonProc;
begin
  PrErrorExistMeans := 0;
  mLog.Lines.Add(Title_File(C_Error_Means));
  raise EExitException.Create(''); // на выход!
end;

procedure myMainProc;
begin
  try
     if ... then
       myCommonProc; // в конце выполнения общего кода возникнет исключение
  except // которое мы перехватываем
    on e: EExitException do ; // наше исключение, это просто Exit
  else
    raise; // это не наше "выходное" исключение, отдаем дальше
  end;
end;
```